# Query execution is taking too long time where table column contains Schema json string

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization

I have SQL Server table and column having schema JSON string as data.

I have to read table record based on `Tenant` column but `schemaName` same across the Tenant.

So the same `schemaName` it should ignore which is read from specific Tenant. for example `demo Tenant`.

Query:

```
SELECT 
    SchemaId, SchemaName, [Schema], Parent, Application, 
    ModifiedDateTime AS ModifiedDateTime, Version, PageType, favorite, 
    CategoryType, Tenant, IsDeleted 
FROM 
    CommonFormsSchema 
WHERE 
    SchemaId IN (SELECT DISTINCT SchemaId 
                 FROM CommonFormsSchema 
                 WHERE Tenant = 'demo'
                 UNION 
                 SELECT DISTINCT SchemaId 
                 FROM CommonFormsSchema 
                 WHERE SchemaName NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SchemaName 
                                          FROM CommonFormsSchema 
                                          WHERE Tenant = 'demo') 
                   AND (Tenant = 'All' OR Tenant IS NULL))
```

but it's taking more time than I have tried like below using a Common Table expression to reduce repeated query

```
WITH FilteredItems as (SELECT DISTINCT SchemaId,SchemaName from CommonFormsSchema WHERE Tenant = 'demo')

SELECT SchemaId, SchemaName, [Schema], Parent, Application, ModifiedDateTime as ModifiedDateTime, Version, PageType, favorite, 
CategoryType, Tenant, IsDeleted FROM CommonFormsSchema 
WHERE SchemaId in (SELECT SchemaId from FilteredItems
UNION SELECT DISTINCT SchemaId FROM CommonFormsSchema WHERE SchemaName NOT IN 
(SELECT SchemaName FROM FilteredItems) AND (Tenant = 'All' OR Tenant IS NULL))
```

But still it is taking more time around 20sec for 200 Records.

**Added Temporary Table Queries for Test:**

```
CREATE TABLE #CommonFormSchemaTest (
    [SchemaId] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [SchemaName] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [Schema] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Parent] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [Application] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [ModifiedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [CreatedDateTime] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [Version] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PageType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Page] [nvarchar](250) NULL,
    [favorite] [bit] NULL,
    [Tenant] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CategoryType] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [IsDeleted] [bit] NULL,
    [ModifiedBy] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [CreatedBy] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [filename] [nvarchar](250) NULL
)

INSERT INTO #CommonFormSchemaTest(SchemaId,SchemaName,[Schema],Tenant) VALUES 
(01, 'Test','{}','demo'),
(02, 'Test','{}','All'),
(03, 'Test','{}','demo2'),
(04, 'Test2','{}','All'),
(05, 'Test3','{}','All')



SELECT 
    SchemaId, SchemaName, [Schema], Parent, Application, 
    ModifiedDateTime AS ModifiedDateTime, Version, PageType, favorite, 
    CategoryType, Tenant, IsDeleted 
FROM 
    #CommonFormSchemaTest 
WHERE 
    SchemaId IN (SELECT DISTINCT SchemaId 
                 FROM #CommonFormSchemaTest 
                 WHERE Tenant = 'demo'
                 UNION 
                 SELECT DISTINCT SchemaId 
                 FROM #CommonFormSchemaTest 
                 WHERE SchemaName NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT SchemaName 
                                          FROM #CommonFormSchemaTest 
                                          WHERE Tenant = 'demo') 
                   AND (Tenant = 'All' OR Tenant IS NULL))
```

**Expected Result:**
[image]
what i have to modify in above query to reduce query repeation clause as well as execution time?
Thanks.

Comment: Please format your queries so we can read it more easily

Comment: `DISTINCT`, and `UNION` without `ALL` is pointless in a subquery, and here the `UNION` is probably messing things up. Split them up into separate subqueries

Comment: @Charlieface can you please provide more clarification on the same or by posting answer with details explaination...i am quite didn't understood

Comment: Can you explain in plain english what this query is supposed to do, as it looks like it may do something different than what you probably think it does?

Comment: we are finding unique row
based on ```SchemaName``` because ```SchemaId``` is different
for Same ```schemaName```.

Comment: But how does `Tenant` come into this, and why does a `group by` not do what you want? And why is your query so convoluted? Please describe in *plain English* what results you actually want.

Comment: @Charlieface could you please look into the question i have updated question with added temprary table for test and expected result.

Comment: Sorry still not getting it. Why can you not just do `DISTINCT` across all the columns?

Comment: please if you don't mind than provide answer how to get performance for the above query.Result already i have mention.

I need in result i.e. is given in above image and result coming correct but with actual data above select query taking more time to return result...so result always will be based on ```Tenant```  column.
for example


Result=Tenant contains  equals to ```demo``` as well as ```All or NULL``` but same  ```schemaName``` of  ```demo.```. if exists in Tenant ```All or Null``` don't take that one.

Comment: I guess I just don't understand the logic behind what you are trying to do. Please explain *in plain english* what the result should look like, and post expected output

Comment: Added expected result.we have to get all rows which is having tenant ```demo,All,Null``` but condition is in result ```schemaName``` will be unique.for example if ```demo``` or ```All``` tenant having same schemaName than select ```demo``` one row.